# Send images by email

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-views

I want to send images by email in a html but when I see the mail the image is broken this is part of my code:

```
data = {
        'image_url': cms.image.url,
       }
subject = 'Recibo de Pago - Shamosh Palombo'
email_body = render_to_string(
    'mails/supplier_receipt_html.html',
    {'data': data, }
)
msg = email_body
headers = {'Reply-To': "contacto@comuna18.com"}
TO = 'mauricio.munguia@comuna18.com'
mail = EmailMessage(subject, msg, 'contacto@comuna18.com', [TO], headers=headers)
mail.content_subtype = "html"
mail.send()
```

And in the template i code like this:

```
<img src="data.image_url" style="width:200px">
```

Comment: Do you want to embed the image in the email so that it can be seen, or do you just want the image to show up as an attachment?

Comment: I want to embed the image in the email so the user can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed the images in the email follow below code. I just added basic code snippet. Please import required imports.

**views.py**

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

mail = EmailMessage(subject, msg, 'contacto@comuna18.com', [TO], headers=headers)
image = MIMEImage(cms.image.open().read())
image.add_header('Content-ID', '<embed_image>')
mail.attach(image)
```

**template.html**

```
<img src="cid:embed_image" style="width:200px">
```

Comment: The terminal show me this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.MIMEImage'" and I install email but the error isn´t going

Comment: The error gone with "from email.mime.image import MIMEImage"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would want to have

```
{{ data.image_url }}
```

in your template.

Example:

```
<img src="{{ data.image_url }}" style="width:200px">
```

I hope this helps!